# Using Gazebo plugin libgazebo_ros_p3d

Tags: ros, gazebo

I am trying to use the Gazebo plugin libgazebo_ros_p3d in order to record my robot's ground truth trajectory in Gazebo, but I haven't been able to get it to work. I have attempted solutions like in https://answers.gazebosim.org//question/5308/getting-the-gazebo-plugin-p3d-working-hydro/, but they don't work, and I am unable to see the topic which should be output by the plugin.

I am using ROS Noetic and Gazebo v11.11. I am also using a simulated Clearpath Jackal, the urdf/xacro file at https://github.com/jackal/jackal/blob/noetic-devel/jackal_description/urdf/jackal.urdf.xacro, and the following gazebo file.

jackal.gazebo

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot>
  <gazebo>
    <plugin name="gazebo_ros_control" filename="libgazebo_ros_control.so">
      <robotNamespace>/</robotNamespace>
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>

  <gazebo>
    <plugin name="imu_controller" filename="libhector_gazebo_ros_imu.so">
      <robotNamespace>/</robotNamespace>
      <updateRate>50.0</updateRate>
      <bodyName>imu_link</bodyName>
      <topicName>imu/data</topicName>
      <accelDrift>0.005 0.005 0.005</accelDrift>
      <accelGaussianNoise>0.005 0.005 0.005</accelGaussianNoise>
      <rateDrift>0.005 0.005 0.005 </rateDrift>
      <rateGaussianNoise>0.005 0.005 0.005 </rateGaussianNoise>
      <headingDrift>0.005</headingDrift>
      <headingGaussianNoise>0.005</headingGaussianNoise>
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>

  <gazebo>
    <plugin name="gps_controller" filename="libhector_gazebo_ros_gps.so">
      <updateRate>40</updateRate>
      <robotNamespace>/</robotNamespace>
      <bodyName>navsat_link</bodyName>
      <frameId>base_link</frameId>
      <topicName>/navsat/fix</topicName>
      <velocityTopicName>/navsat/vel</velocityTopicName>
      <referenceLatitude>$(optenv GAZEBO_WORLD_LAT 49.9)</referenceLatitude>
  <referenceLongitude>$(optenv GAZEBO_WORLD_LON 8.9)</referenceLongitude>
      <referenceHeading>90</referenceHeading>
      <referenceAltitude>0</referenceAltitude>
      <drift>0.0001 0.0001 0.0001</drift>
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>
  
  <!-- for ground truth trajectory --> 
  <gazebo>
    <plugin name="p3d_base_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_p3d.so">
      <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
      <updateRate>50.0</updateRate>
      <bodyName>base_link</bodyName>
      <topicName>ground_truth/state</topicName>
      <gaussianNoise>0.01</gaussianNoise>
      <frameName>world</frameName>
      <xyzOffsets>0 0 0</xyzOffsets>
      <rpyOffsets>0 0 0</rpyOffsets>
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>

  <gazebo reference="base_link">
    <turnGravityOff>false</turnGravityOff>
  </gazebo>

  <gazebo reference="chassis_link">
    <material>Gazebo/DarkGrey</material>
    <turnGravityOff>false</turnGravityOff>
  </gazebo>
  <gazebo reference="imu_link">
    <turnGravityOff>false</turnGravityOff>
  </gazebo>

  <gazebo reference="navsat_link">
    <material>Gazebo/DarkGrey</material>
    <turnGravityOff>false</turnGravityOff>
  </gazebo>
  <gazebo reference="front_fender_link">
    <material>Gazebo/Yellow</material>
    <turnGravityOff>false</turnGravityOff>
  </gazebo>
  <gazebo reference="rear_fender_link">
    <material>Gazebo/Yellow</material>
    <turnGravityOff>false</turnGravityOff>
  </gazebo>
</robot>
```

The other plugins in the file work just fine, and I can see their topics, but libgazebo_ros_p3d is not. If anyone could help me solve this issue, I would really appreciate it.